# How folded a widget on screen in Web App Builder?

Tags: dojo, arcgis-web-appbuilder, widget

I want make that a window like this
[image]

Has the foldable behaviour, like this foldable window:
[image]

I need a window foldable, moveable and resizable, any idea?

Answer (score 1):

The behavior you're talking about is inherited when it is an ["In-panel" widget](https://developers.arcgis.com/web-appbuilder/guide/in-panel-and-off-panel-widget.htm) (so it shows up in the header with the collapse option).  If you are creating a custom widget, you can set the `inPanel` property to `true` in the Widget Manifest file:

[image]

Or if you add it to the Header Controller it will automatically be an in panel widget:

[image]

**Then simply add your widget:**

[image]

Comment: The inPanel propertie it's true in the manifest of my widget. I need a window foldable, moveable and resizable, so if I put  my widget en the header controller, will be foldable, but not moveable or resizable.

Comment: In that case, it's kind of hacky, but maybe you could just hijack some of the html/css and add a div with the classes esri uses.  For example `<div class="foldable-btn jimu-vcenter jimu-float-trailing fold-up" data-dojo-attach-point="foldableNode" data-dojo-attach-event="onclick:_onFoldableBtnClicked" style="display:block; margin-top: 17.5px;></div>"`.  I have not tested but should work in theory.  Keep in mind though, this stuff is automatically added when a mobile devices is used so you may want to do some media queries first...

Comment: Thanks, its a good idea. Now I just have the problem that when I maximize the window, it doen't maintain position or original size

Comment: Yeah, that may be beyond your control as it is probably WAB/jimu overriding css.